# Detecting locale from unicode string in c++

Tags: c++, unicode

I have a string and I want to check if the content is in English or Hindi(My local language). I figured out that the unicode range for hindi character is from U0900-U097F.

What is the simplest way to find if the string has any characters in this range?

I can use std::string or Glib::ustring depending on whichever is convenient.

Comment: What is the encoding you are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you do it with Glib::ustring :

```
using Glib::ustring;

ustring x("सहस");    // hindi string
bool is_hindi = false;
for (ustring::iterator i = x.begin(); i != x.end(); i ++)
    if (*i >= 0x0900 && *i <= 0x097f)
        is_hindi = true;
```

Comment: The "सहस" bit isn't portable, neither in theory nor in practice. It works iff you have a `char` encoding that support Hindi. As Hindi is just U0900-U097F you can append that to ASCII and still fit it in 8 bits, so I'll assume such encodings exist.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is writing a functor to tell if a given wchar_t is Hindi. This will be (derived from) a `std::unary_function<wchar_t, bool>`. Implementation is trivial: `return c>= 0x0900 && c < 0x980;`. The second step is using it: `std::find_if(begin, end, is_hindi())`.

Since you'll need Unicode, you should probably use `wchar_t` and therefore `std::wstring`.  Neither `std::string` nor `GLib::ustring` supports Unicode proper. On some systems (Windows in particular) the implementation of `wchar_t` is restricted to Unicode 4 = 16 bits but that should still be enough for 99.9% of the worlds population.

You'll need to convert from/to UTF-8 on I/O, but the advantage of "one character = one wchar_t" is big. For instance, `std::wstring::substr()` will work reasonably. You might still have issues with "characters" like U+094B (DEVANAGARI VOWEL SIGN O), though. When iterating over a std::wstring, that will appear to be a character by itself, instead of a modifier. That's still better than std::string with UTF-8, where you'd end up iterating over the individual bytes of U+094B. And to take just your original examples, none of the bytes in `UTF8(U+094B)` are reserved for Hindi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would the comparison statement inside the functor look like?

Comment: Why do you say GLib::ustring doesn't support Unicode properly?

Comment: @ltcmelo, he didn't write "properly", he wrote "proper". What this means is that one can use, for instance, std::string to support Unicode, but std::string itself knows nothing about Unicode.

Comment: I tried a Hindi word with Glib::ustring and it supports unicode very well. I tried with GCC 4.3.3 on Linux and with GCC 4.4.0 on Windows

Comment: @Rob K - Yes, I know that. But I asked about Glib::ustring, which he also said doesn't support Unicode. I'm curious about that because in my understanding the whole point of Glib::ustring is to represent UTF-8 properly. Perhaps he was talking about other encodings than UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

If the string is already encoded as UTF-8, I would not convert it to UTF-16 (I assume that's what MSalters calls "Unicode proper") but iterate through the UTF-8 encoded string and check whether there is a Hindi character in it.

With std::string, you can easily iterate with the help of the [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net) library:  - take a look at utf8::next() function, or the iterator class.

GLib::ustring has an [iterator](http://www.gtkmm.org/docs/glibmm-2.4/docs/reference/html/classGlib_1_1ustring__Iterator.html) that seems to enable the same functionality (haven't tried it):